# Calling a class that has been initialized in another function

Tags: c++, function-call

following problem:

I have two classes that organize the loading procedure of my config file and my database.
I use those classes by initializing them and calling their individual functions.
I am now trying to get some structure into my code, so I want to make my main-class function-based.
Here is a code sample of my main-class (theWholeThing.cpp)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "VN_DB.cpp"
#include "iostream"
#include "sstream"
#include "map"
#include "string"
#include "iterator"
#include "VN_chk.cpp"
#include "Execute.cpp"
#include "ConfigFile.cpp"

using namespace std;

class theWholeThing {

int db_width;
int act_free;
string act_free_str;
map <string, string> config;
string master_path;
string download_path;
int ausfuehren;

map <string, vector<string>> data;

private:

void getConfig() {

    //Lade CONFIG via ConfigFile
    ConfigFile cfg("config.cfg");
    config = cfg.getCFG();
    string act_free_str = config["act_free"];
    act_free = atoi(act_free_str.c_str());
    string db_width_str = config["db_width"];
    db_width = atoi(db_width_str.c_str());
    master_path = config["master_path"];
    download_path = config["download_path"];
}


void getDatabase() {

    //Lade Database via VN_DB
    VN_DB db ("export.csv", db_width, act_free);
    data = db.getData();

    for (map <string, vector <string>>::iterator it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); it++) {
        string id;
        string buffer;
        id = it->first + " ";

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < it->second.size(); i++) {
            buffer = buffer + it->second[i];
        }
        cout << buffer << endl;
    }
}

void ioMenu() {
    cout << "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    " << "Menu" << "    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@" << endl;
    cout << "Welche Funktion moechten sie nutzen? \n" << endl;
    cout << "(1) Neues Programm \n" << "(2) Programm löschen \n" << "(3) Programm suchen \n" << "(4) Programm updaten \n" << "(5) Alle Programme updaten \n" << "(6) Datenbank exportieren \n" << endl << endl;
    cin >> ausfuehren;
    switch (ausfuehren) {
    case 1: //...
    case 2: //...
    case 3: //...
    case 4: //...
    case 5: //...
    case 6: //...
    default: 
    }
}

void addProgram() {
    string temp_name;
    string temp_path;
    vector <string> ibuffer;
    cout << "Name des Programms: " << endl;
    cin >> ibuffer.at(0);
    cout << "Pfad der Installationspakete" << endl;
    cin >> ibuffer.at(1);
    cout << "Name des Installationspaketes" << endl;
    cin >> ibuffer.at(2);
    cout << "Versionsnummer des Installationspaketes" << endl;
    cin >> ibuffer.at(3);
    db.newProg("03", ibuffer);
    act_free++;
    stringstream ss;
    ss << act_free;
    act_free_str = ss.str();
    config["act_free"] = act_free_str;
    cfg.WriteConfig(config);
}


public:

theWholeThing() {

    getConfig();
    getDatabase();
    ioMenu();
}

};
```

But now I cant call the functions of these two classes in my other functions because "db" and "cfg" are not defined yet.

I am new to programming in such complexity so I want to ask what would be the best way to fix this?

I want to be able to call all functions implemented in my ConfigFile.cpp and VN_DB.cpp from all of my functions in my main class.

Comment: How are you trying to use these functions? I think you just need to return the Config and VN_DB objecs from these functions and perform the actions on the object instances.

Comment: To use functions defined in classes in files `ConfigFile.cpp` and `VN_DB.cpp`, you must include their corresponding **header files** in files where you want to use them(e.g. where main() is defined). Another point is that you can return objects instead of `void` from functions `getConfig()` and `getDatabase`

Comment: I want to use functions from these classes in all functions in my main class, simply by using "db.changeValues(x)" or "cfg.writeConfig(y)".

Comment: Return those objects from functions `getConfig()` and `getDatabase()` and also include corresponding header files (because db and cfg are class objects) in your main.cpp because without it your code won't compile!

Comment: @pravar: I have the .cpp files included.
If I want to use these class objects after I returned them, how do I store them correctly?

Comment: Don't include cpp files else you will get linker errors

Answer (score 1):

Both `getConfig` and `getDatabase` seem like names for functions that return something. Yours don't. You should return what you initialized inside (by value, if that's possible), then you'll be able to work with it:

```
map<string, string> getConfig()
{
    ...
    return config;
}

map<string, vector<string>> getDatabase()
{
    ...
    return data;
}
```

Comment: You are quicker by a few seconds!

Comment: They dont really return sth. They just call the "import-classes" to get the important values from the config and database into variables, which I can then use in my class.

Comment: @Alexander Their names *suggest* that these functions return something, so they *should*. How else do you want to get the `map`s out of them?

Comment: @LogicStuff: You´re right I forgot to edit this so far and the names are a bit misleading (I am just coding for myself so the code is hard to read). I wanted to store those values in variables inside the main class. I will edit the Code-Sample.

Comment: The Code-Samples are from my main class yes.

Comment: Still, I don't see the `class` and the problem. I don't even know what "calling a class" means.

Comment: Added code of the whole class (sry didnt want to put a huge code sample in there as the form somehow looks strange after copying it in here)

I wanted to say "They call functions inside these classes..."

Comment: Ok, seriously, where's the problem? Your `config` and `data` are private members, you can write public accessors.

Comment: The problem is that I dont know how I can call the functions of VN_DB/ConfigFile from other functions of theWholeThing. And I want to know how I can reach that goal the most elegant way.
Like I said in the question....

Comment: Since they are local objects, they get destructed after the functions returns. Make them members, too.

Comment: Ok, gonna read myself through some material about member functions then. ty